# How to draw 3D objects in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to draw 3D objects in Jetpack Compose?

I want to draw a cube and rotate it.
I could find any samples or tutorials for it except [this](https://proandroiddev.com/compose-camera-and-canvas-87b8cfed8cda).

But this was too difficult for me.

Comment: The example you found seems to focus in the math implementation of the task that the guy decided to work on. However, if you see, you can note the "way" how he is doing that task. Search by the Canvas composable, which provides the API you need to draw your cube. Also, to draw a cube you should be a little able to deal with linear algebra and some other graphics math concepts.

Answer (score 0):

To draw a cube and simulate its rotation, you can follow these steps:

**1.Create a Composable for the Cube:**

```
@Composable
fun Cube() {
    // Draw the front face of the cube
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Blue)
    )

    // Draw the right face of the cube
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Green)
            .graphicsLayer(rotationZ = 90f)
    )

    // Draw the top face of the cube
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Red)
            .graphicsLayer(rotationX = 90f)
    )
}
```

**2.Rotate the Cube:**

```
@Composable
fun RotatingCube() {
    val rotationState = rememberInfiniteTransition()
    val angle by rotationState.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0f,
        targetValue = 360f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis = 2000, easing = LinearEasing)
        )
    )

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .graphicsLayer(
                rotationX = angle,
                rotationY = angle
            )
    ) {
        Cube()
    }
}
```

**3.You can now use the RotatingCube composable in your UI:**

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    RotatingCube()
}
```